# Obter dimensão original da imagem com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma imagem carregada na minha página HTML dentro da *tag* **`<img>`**, há alguma forma de saber dimensão do arquivo original dela por *JavaScript*?

Digamos que eu queira dar um `console.log(larguraImagem, alturaImagem);`.

> Note que o tamanho que eu quero saber é o original que está no
>   servidor e não o que está sendo exibido na tela porque este pode estar
>   sendo redimensionado pelo CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que a única maneira cross-browser que inclui browsers antigos é assíncrona, criando uma nova imagem com o [construtor `new Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image).

Para browsers modernos podes usar o [`naturalHeight` e `naturalWidth`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=img-naturalwidth-naturalheight) (exemplo em baixo)

Uma aplicação prática seria assim:

```js
function getImgSize(image) {
  const newImg = new Image();
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    newImg.onload = function() {
      const height = newImg.height;
      const width = newImg.width;
      res({
        width: newImg.width,
        height: newImg.height
      });
    }
    newImg.src = image.src;
  });
}

const img = document.querySelector('img');
getImgSize(img).then(size => console.log(size));
```

```css
img {
  width 10%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/02/23/05/sunrise-1565344_960_720.jpg" />
```

Com `naturalHeight` e `naturalWidth`:

```js
function getImgSize(image) {
  return {
  width: image.naturalWidth,
  height: image.naturalHeight
  }
}

const img = document.querySelector('img');
const size = getImgSize(img);
console.log(size);
```

```css
img {
  width 10%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/02/23/05/sunrise-1565344_960_720.jpg" />
```

Comment: Excelente resposta! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando achei o seguinte cod:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 

var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

so que isso vai retornar o tamanho dela de acordo com o DOM isso é o tamanho dela exibido no seu navegador ( isso é influenciável pela css )
para resolver isto você deve utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
var originalwidth = img.naturalHeight;
var originalheight = img.naturalWidth;
```

com este comando você pega os tamanhos originais da imagem independendo do DOM

Answer (score -1):

Pode fazer assim...

```js
let imagem = document.getElementById('imagem') 

let width = imagem.clientWidth;
let height = imagem.clientHeight;

alert(width + ' - ' + height)
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/card_landscape_930_524/2017/08/courtesy_of_hbo_photo_11-h_2017.jpg" id="imagem">
```