# Acrescentar width/height original nas tags de imagens

Tags: html, css

Existe alguma forma de passar código CSS para tag do HTML?
Exemplo, tenho a tag abaixo:

```
<img src="../img/cS-1.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
```

todo código de css que eu colocar para essa imagem aparacer dentro da tag img quando eu for no navegador e inspecionar elemento?
Exemplo ficar desta forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso na verdade apenas do tamanho original da foto dentro da tag

Comment: Com JS vc consegue colocar o style direto na tag, ou então na mão mesmo ,colocando <img style="width:100px; height:100px;"...>. Na Developer Tools do Chrome vc tb pode consultar a altura e largura da imagem (atalho f12 no teclado)

Comment: Não pode ser na mão, é para indexar no google no momento que usuário subir a imagem no CMS o tamanho tem que ir para tag, como faço isso em JS tem algum exemplo?

Comment: você quer colocar dentro de uma tag `<i>conteudo</i>` onde conteudo seria os height e width de uma imagem ?

Comment: Está um pouco confuso isso ai...haha. Resumindo se o tamanho original da minha foto for de 100x100 dentro da minha tag <img> precisa estar desta forma <img src="../img/cS-1.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width:100px; height:100px> precisa aparecer dentro da tag entende?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Obter dimensão original da imagem com JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239696/obter-dimens%c3%a3o-original-da-imagem-com-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `naturalWidth` e `naturalHeight` que retorna as dimensões originais da imagem e inserir no *style* do elemento. Mas, para tornar mais fácil a seleção, adicione uma `class` (ou `id`) ao elemento:

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.imagem');

img.style.width = img.naturalWidth+'px';
img.style.height = img.naturalHeight+'px';
```

```html
<img class="imagem" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Basketball.jpeg/220px-Basketball.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Show de bola, é exatamente isso que precisava, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmpImg = new Image();
tmpImg.src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054"; //or  document.images[i].src;
$(tmpImg).on('load',function(){
  var orgWidth = tmpImg.width;
  var orgHeight = tmpImg.height;
  alert(orgWidth+"x"+orgHeight);
});
```

Utilize esse script você pode ver ele em  [funcionamento aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/z0L62wkh/)

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda Marcos, show o script

Comment: por nada,  se tiver dado certo marca a resposta  como  solucionada clicando em ✓✓