# Altura x Largura - JavaScript - Imagem Externa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar o valor de altura e largura de uma imagem externa, com Javascript/Jquery, ou seja, sem estar implementada no código a imagem.

Comment: Veja se as respostas dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239696/obter-dimens%C3%A3o-original-da-imagem-com-javascript) te ajuda.

Comment: Não isso é uma imagem que está no html.

Comment: Eu respondi isso [no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363955/get-each-image-natural-height-with-jquery/30035502#30035502)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `new Image` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

Para pegar a largura e altura originais da imagem use:

- `naturalWidth`
- `naturalHeight`

Conforme descrito em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Exemplo:

```js
function getImageSize(url, success, error) {
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function () {
        success(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
    };
    img.onerror = error;
    img.src = url;
}

getImageSize("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShnZP.png?s=328&g=1", function (largura, altura) {
   console.log("largura: " + largura, "altura: " + altura);
}, function () {
   console.log("Erro ao carregar a imagem");
});

getImageSize("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/img/sprites.svg?v=554232ea0d79", function (largura, altura) {
   console.log("largura: " + largura, "altura: " + altura);
}, function () {
   console.log("Erro ao carregar a imagem");
});
```

Se deseja pegar o tamanho de uma imagem já inserida na página, pode usar `document.getElementByID` ou `document.querySelector` (depende de como estiver a imagem), por exemplo:

```js
function getHtmlImageSize(img, success, error) {
    if (img.complete) {
         complete();
         return;
    }

    img.addEventListener("error", fail);
    img.addEventListener("load", complete);

    function complete() {
         if (img.naturalWidth) {
             success(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
         } else {
              error();
         }
         finish();
    }

    function fail() {
         error();
         finish();
    }

    function finish() {
        img.removeEventListener("error", error);
        img.removeEventListener("load", complete);
    }
}

//Pega a imagem no HTML
var img1 = document.querySelector(".some-class > img");

getHtmlImageSize(img1, function (largura, altura) {
   console.log("largura: " + largura, "altura: " + altura);
}, function () {
   console.log("Erro ao carregar a imagem");
});
```

```html
<div class="some-class">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObF0n.gif">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Conforme respondi no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30035502/3096922), você pode utilizar o jQuery, fazendo assim:

```js
var src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWWpy.png';

$('<img>').attr({src: src}).on('load', function () {
    console.log(this.naturalHeight);
    console.log(this.naturalWidth);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```